# Confusion related to regularization parameter selection by cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, regularization

I can see lots of paper mentioning they selected some parameters like regularization parameter $\lambda$ by cross validation. What do they mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Optimal values for things like regularization parameters cannot (always) be computed in advance. Often, we are forced to pick a value and see what happens (e.g. train a model with a given value and assess its performance).

[Cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) is a very popular method to test the performance for a given value of the parameter $\lambda$. The value which yields the best cross-validation performance is then selected.